# how to know when some operation on a dataframe affects the original data or not (so I need to reassign its name)?

Tags: python, pandas, variable-assignment

I am new to `pandas`, and something that I find difficult to understand is whether the operations I run on a dataframe (or a series) affect the original data, or I need to reassign the name of the dataframe to the modified one.

For instance, I know that using:

`my_list.add('one_more')`

will modify `my_list` so I dont need to reassign its name:

However, if df is a dataframe:

`df.ix[mask,:]=0`

will not modify my dataframe `df`, so I need to type:

`df=df.ix[mask,:]=0`

Is there a rule that I am missing that allow me to know when I need to reassign a variable name or not?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you show code that demonstrates that `df.ix[mask,:]=0` doesn't modify your df as it depends

Comment: Hi @EdChum thanks for your answer. Actually that is the point, it seems to depend. how can I know that in advance? there must be a list of functions/operations that need reassignement and others that do not, right?

Comment: it should warn you that you're operating on a copy rather than a view though, but this doesn't catch all situations

Comment: the ipythong console should warn me? the help file of the method I call?

Comment: the output of your code so `df.ix[mask,:]=0` should output a warning in your output in ipython